pest parser grabbing extra whitespace after an optional argument
I have a pest grammar for parsing the GraphViz dot language, which I have included below.
The following statement in the dot language is a "edge_stmt" with an optional label (it names an edge between nodes "a" and "b" in a graph):
a -> b [color=red]
However, when my pest grammar parses this, it parses node a as "a" and b as "b " with a trailing space, which I don't understand, as I think it should gobble up the WHITESPACE with the separator ~.
Interestingly, if I get rid of the optional port, I don't see this behavior.  That is, if I change:
node_id   = { ident ~ port? }

to:
node_id   = { ident }

then b is parsed as "b" with no trailing space.
I am unsure why this should affect the whitespace parsing, or why I should ever get "b " in the first place.  Am I missing something in my grammar, or could this be some sort of pest known issue or bug?
dotgraph = { strict? ~ (graph | digraph) ~ ident? ~ "{" ~ stmt_list ~ "}" }

stmt_list = { (stmt ~ ";"? ~ stmt_list)? }
stmt      = { subgraph | edge_stmt | attr_stmt | id_eq | node_stmt }

attr_stmt = { (graph | node | edge) ~ attr_list }
attr_list = { "[" ~ a_list ~ "]" ~ attr_list? }
a_list    = { ident ~ "=" ~ ident ~ (";" | ",")? ~ a_list? }

edge_stmt =  { node_id ~ edge_rhs ~ attr_list? }
edge_rhs  =  { edgeop ~ node_id ~ edge_rhs? }
edgeop    = _{ "--" | "->" }

node_stmt = { node_id ~ attr_list? }
node_id   = { ident ~ port? }
port      = { ":" ~ ident }

ident     = _{ (ASCII_ALPHA | "_") ~ (ASCII_ALPHANUMERIC | "_")* }

WHITESPACE = _{ " " | "\t" | NEWLINE }

...

